# PostgreSQL database connection time

Tags: postgresql, timeout

How much Time does psql client takes to connect to PostgreSQL server ?

Comment: What do you mean exaclty?  Who tries to connect where?

Answer (score -1):

Try with this query does the trick:

```
select *
from pg_stat_activity
where datname = 'mydatabasename';
```

Info:

See [this closely related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17655766/398670).

`pg_stat_activity` is a view in the `pg_catalog` schema.

You can query it by `SELECT`ing from it like any other table, eg `SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity`. The manual page you linked to explains its columns.

You'll sometimes find yourself wanting to join on other tables like `pg_class` (tables), `pg_namespace` (schemas), etc.

`pg_stat_activity` does *not* expose information about back-end memory use. You need to use operating-system level facilities for that. It *does* tell you the process ID, active user, currently running query, activity status, time the last query started, etc. It's good for identifying long-running `idle in transaction` sessions, very long running queries, etc.

Frankly, PostgreSQL's built-in monitoring is rather rudimentary. It's one of the areas that's not that exciting to work on, and commercial clients aren't often willing to fund it. Most people couple tools like [`check_postgres`](http://bucardo.org/wiki/Check_postgres) with Icinga and Munin, or use Zabbix or other external monitoring agents.

In your case it sounds like you really want `pg_stat_statements`, and/or PgBadger log analysis with suitable logging settings and possibly the `auto_explain` module.

Credits to: [Craig Ringer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/398670/craig-ringer)

Comment: I am not sure how this answers a question which is basically unclear at the moment (see my comment above).  How do you get any information from `pg_stat_activity` about the time needed for opening a connection?